# When a strong symbol and weak symbol have different data types, whose data type is chosen?

Tags: c, linker

If I have two different C files like this:

main.c

```
void f(void);
int x = 38;
int y = 39;

int main()
{
 f();
 printf("x = %d\n", x);
 printf("y = %d\n", y);
 return 0;
}
```

swap.c

```
double x;
void f()
{
 x = 42.0;
}
```

My question is since int x is the stronger symbol here, shouldn't  "x"  be initialized as an int and when function f is called, x = 42.0 would simply store x with only 42. But instead x becomes 0 since a double is being written into an int.

When the program is run, after linking both the files, we get this output:

```
x = 0
y = 1078263808
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with weak symbols and everything to do with undefined behavior.

Comment: Doesn't value of `y` seem unexpected(or better wierd) to you ?

Comment: @ameyCU: With Undefined Behaviour, the unexpected is expected.

Comment: @rici Comment was intended for OP for his attention on `y` , as he was worried about `x` , but nevermind .

Comment: IMHO - the better choice over "undefined behavior" would have been a well defined linker error "Same symbol with different types". But unfortunately, I have no say in that :)

Comment: @BitTickler: That would require that linkers know the type of every external symbol. An implementation which happens to have this information available is free to produce a diagnostic message, but it seems massively unlikely that compiler vendors would accept making the inclusion of this information in object files *obligatory*.

Comment: @ameyCU yeah I forgot to mention about y but I did guess it was behaving weirdly because of the x's in the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in the "strength" of the two declarations of `x` in those two files. However, the fact that the declarations differ and that `x` has external linkage in both files makes linking the two into a single executable Undefined Behaviour.

The consequence, as you can see, is that the program does not produce sensible output.

In a typical C implementation, the linker will not notice declaration mismatches like this, and the C standard does not require a diagnostic message to be emitted. But it is still an invalid program.

#### Mandatory standard references:

§6.2.7 Compatible type/paragraph 2:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

§5.1.1.3 Diagnostics/paragraph 1:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message … [if a] translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint … Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances